# Convert Rect to RectF

Tags: android, android-canvas, rectangles

Whats the best way to convert a Rect variable to a RectF one? I am unable to cast it.

```
RectF rect = (RectF) currentRect; //produces an error
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the best way to convert from a RectF to a Rect in Android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16449145/what-is-the-best-way-to-convert-from-a-rectf-to-a-rect-in-android)

Answer (score 22):

```
RectF rect = new RectF(currentRect);
```

Answer (score 5):

As "new" shouldn't be done in onDraw,

```
// As class fields,
Rect rect = new Rect();
RectF rectF = new RectF();

...
onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    ...
    rectF.set(rect);
    ...
}
```