# What is Rectf roundout(Rect dest ) function?

Tags: android, android-canvas

What is the  **roundout()** function in **Rectf**. What is the exact functionality of **roundOut(Rect dest)** function. Can any one explain this with example how this function works?

Answer (score 1):

[public void roundOut (Rect dst)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/RectF.html#roundOut%28android.graphics.Rect%29)

```
Added in API level 1
```

> Set the dst integer Rect by rounding "out" this rectangle, choosing
>   the floor of top and left, and the ceiling of right and bottom.

[public static double floor (double d)](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Math.html#floor%28double%29)

Added in API level 1

> Returns the double conversion of the most positive (closest to
>   positive infinity) integer value less than or equal to the argument.
>
> Special cases:
>
> ```
> floor(+0.0) = +0.0
> floor(-0.0) = -0.0
> floor(+infinity) = +infinity
> floor(-infinity) = -infinity
> floor(NaN) = NaN
> ```

[public static double ceil (double d)](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Math.html#ceil%28double%29)
Added in API level 1

> Returns the double conversion of the most negative (closest to
>   negative infinity) integer value greater than or equal to the
>   argument.
>
> Special cases:
>
> ```
> ceil(+0.0) = +0.0
> ceil(-0.0) = -0.0
> ceil((anything in range (-1,0)) = -0.0
> ceil(+infinity) = +infinity
> ceil(-infinity) = -infinity
> ceil(NaN) = NaN
> ```

```
RectF rectF = new RectF(0.0f, 0.0f, 10.5f, 20.f);
Rect rect = new Rect();
rectF.roundOut(rect);// Now rect will contains these values Rect(0, 0, 11, 20)

//What happens inside roundOut function
Math.floor(0.0f);//Results 0
Math.floor(0.0f);//Results 0
Math.ceil(10.5f);//Results 10
Math.ceil(20.f);//Results 20
```

Comment: shall you suggest any example code implementing above function?

Comment: 'rectF.roundOut(new Rect(0, 0, 30, 35));'  after this how the rectf will change?

Answer (score 1):

`rountRect` will give you a `Rect` Object.

So

```
   Rect rect = new Rect();

   rectFObj.roundout(rect);
```

Now rect contains all values of RectF object but they are now rounded off means 1.1 becomes 1

Answer (score 0):

One of the use which I found while searching is that roundout(Rect) is used for converting from RectF to Rect, using.

```
rectF.roundOut(rect);
```

Source - [What is the best way to convert from a RectF to a Rect in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16449145/what-is-the-best-way-to-convert-from-a-rectf-to-a-rect-in-android)